# MySQL query: Closest < result from query

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table: cm_rank
|id|rankpoeng|tittel  |
-----------------------
|1 |        0 |Sivil  |
|2 |      322 |Wannabe|
|3 |     1450 |Hitman |
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
$currentXp = 500;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_rank WHERE $currentXp > rankpoeng LIMIT 1");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    $levelTitle = $rows['title'];
    echo $levelTitle;
endwhile;
```

The `$levelTitle` variable should only hold the text "Wannabe", since the users has more xp than it requires, but not enought for the next rank.

How may I structure up a query like this?

Comment: So what defines `but not enought for the next rank.` ? Is there a bench mark ?

Answer (score 1):

You should order by rankpoeng column to take the highest valid value.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_rank WHERE $currentXp > rankpoeng ORDER BY rankpoeng DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: @Hansen: and note that you don't need while loop when you have `LIMIT 1`, use directyl `$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to order the result:

```
"SELECT * FROM cm_rank WHERE $currentXp > rankpoeng order by rankpoeng desc LIMIT 1"
```

But you should not use the deprecated `mysql_*` API. You should use `mysqli_*`or PDO with prepared statement.